# How to create a new window when there's a TypeError?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display an error message whenever it happens. So in tkinter I want tkinter to open a new window that contains an error dialogue or something like "You are trying to extract more units than there's inside the store your record has been ignored." so whenever there's a TypeError.
The program is a data entry GUI and I want the program to warn the user that he's doing a mistake. I want and intend to ignore it as a developer but I need the user to see it.

I've searched for it a lot but I can't seem to find a working solution
I imagine it's something like

```
try:
    do nothing  #Continue running code like nothing happened or in other words, ignore the whole try statement 
except TypeError:
   create a new window
```

The cause of this error I know to be the user trying to extract 5 units out of the data base while there's only 4 of that type. Then it returns a TypeError.

How is it done ? I know it's possible and I've searched a lot but I'm just a beginner and I couldn't understand most available solutions so please simplify your solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you really shouldn't be ignoring TypeErrors. The error is telling you that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I know and it's intended. I'm using that error to warn the user that he's doing something wrong. This is kind of a GUI or a Desktop app for data entry and I want this to warn the user that he just tried to get out more of a product than there actually is. I want it to happen and appear to the user. The program automatically doesn't insert data when that error happens. I want to tell the user that he just made a mistake and his entry is invalid. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It's unclear what you're doing that is causing a `TypeError`. It's also why you want to create a new window rather than keep the existing window, and whether the new window is identical to the original window of if it's some sort of error dialog.

Comment: I'm sorry, what does [mncve] mean ?

Comment: @MohamedAmr: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] dialog`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+dialog)

Comment: It means I misspelled "mcve" - it originally stood for _minimal, complete, verifiable example_. Now it gets replaced with _minimum reproducible example_

Comment: @stovfl I can't understand these solutions. I feel like they are really unrelated to my question. Or I misunderstood. I'm sorry.

Comment: @MohamedAmr: ***"can't understand these solutions"***: You are looking for a error message dialog?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a window that'll pop up and tell the user that an error happened. But I still can't get these.